# Finding the source code behind a web page feature

Tags: javascript, html, web, inspector

I'm pretty new to Web Development and am beginning to fool around looking at different 'features' websites have. I have recently come across the [StarCraft remastered page](https://starcraft.com/en-us/) and halfway down the page they have a "window" in which you man slide a slider back and forth seeing the old graphics and the new graphics of a scene. I think this is really neat and am wondering if I can find the source code of how they achieve this effect. [Here is the image of the described "window".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2USWQ.jpg)

Also, as a side note, is it unethical to try to recreate a features I find on other sites? I'm really new to this and I don't know what is okay and what is not and I don't think I would be able to create that feature myself without seeing how they acheived it.

Answer (score 0):

Not unethical at all, this is how web developers learn new stuff. In general, the developer tools of your browser should become your best friend.

Regarding the example that you provided, essentially this can be achieved with a ui control that is commonly called "divider" or "split panel". And you can find a lot of plugins that provide such functionality (ex split.js). With this, and a bit of css for styling, you can achieve the same effect as the one you liked in starcraft page.

Answer (score 0):

On any modern browser of choice, right click your mouse on the image, then click 'Inspect', 'Inspect Element' or some variant thereof depending on browser and version. I'm using the most recent version of Chrome which is just 'Inspect'.

This will open your developer tools to get a deeper look into the front-end of a website or web application.

Comment: Gotcha. I know about the inspector but I don't really understand how to find the Javascript portion effecting the DOM element.

Comment: At a quick glance it appears to be done with CSS.

Basically both clips are playing at the same time directly on top of each other. Depending on the position of the slider, visibility (or width in this specific instance) of the div containing the original version's clip is displayed or hidden depending on the slider's location.

With dev tools open, take on your 'Elements' tab, slide back and forth and notice CSS classes being added or removed, along with the div containing the original version's animated clip's width being adjusted depending on position.